# Excel, how to delete sheets without breaking formula references

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to delete sheets from a workbook w/o breaking formula references; is there a way to do this via code or settings?

Comment: What do you want to happen instead of the references breaking? Your question doesn't give much to go on...

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm late to the party, but I found a useful and simple workaround. Let's say you're trying to VLOOKUP into a sheet that is constantly replaced (Sheet2). This is your formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A:$B,2,FALSE)
```

The second you delete Sheet2, reference will break. But if you keep replacing Sheet2 with sheets named the same way, do this:

On a random cell, let's say AA1, write:

```
Sheet2!$A:$B
```

Don't use the equal sign. You want it as pure text.

Then change your VLOOKUP to:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,INDIRECT($AA$1),2,FALSE)
```

Pure text is not affected by references being erased, so this should leave your code safe.

Comment: This should be the top answer!

Answer (score 4):

My free Mappit! addin available from http://www.experts-exchange.com/A_2613.html has as one of its outputs a map that shows worksheet relationships

You could use this to detect where the potential issues from sheet deletion may arise

[image]

Comment: Due to the nature of SO, you will get less downvoting if you host your module elsewhere ;)

Comment: Hi Michel, that certainly hasn't been my experience here thus far, it's very much about solution competency not origin. Plus ive always found the excel topics (at any forum) tend to stay above the site v site debates.

Comment: Great. It was however downvoted for some reason. I voted it back up.

Comment: well there you go - I must have missed the earlier downvote that you were referring to. Thanks for that

Comment: The link is broken :(

Comment: It's now on my onedrive account - pls see my stackoverflow profile :)

Answer (score 1):

Copy all the formulas. Paste as formulas to another area (say a sheet just to save them that you can then hide). On the sheet with the formula backups, Find "=", Replace with "|" (or any other seldom used character). Whenever you need the formulas, you need only paste them where they need to be then Find "|" and Replace with "=" (include none of the "quotes").

Doing this allows you to easily fix the formulas you may have broken. I usually break mine by removing the worksheet with the cells referenced in the formulas. I use this technique to fix tables generated by power query when it does not populate the table with the same column order as the query. The process is to Load to Connection Only (which deletes the data that was referenced by my formulas), then Load to Worksheet, forcing a rebuilding of the table, with the same column order as the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hard coding to a specific sheet that would be impossible. Are you implying you would like the dependency to be shifted to another sheet?

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, cannot delete the sheet without breaking the reference.  However here are some options depending on your circumstances:

1. Copy/paste special:values to retain the result of the formula and delete the sheet.
2. Hide the sheet and protect the workbook instead of deleting the sheet.
3. Change the references to a sheet in another workbook.

Answer (score 0):

this is 4 years after but i wanted to leave my solution here in case it helps anyone having the same issue

Process:

1. Cut (CTRL+X) the cell and it's contents that your formula is referencing from the 1st sheet (sheet that is going to be deleted, ex.: Sheet!$A$1)
2. Paste the cut cell in the 2nd sheet at the new or same location (sheet that is going to be kept, ex.: Paste it in Sheet2!A1)
3. Do this for all cells that needs to be transferred over
4. Check the formulas to make sure they are referencing the 2nd sheet (**Sheet2!** instead of **Sheet1!**)
5. Delete the 1st sheet
6. Rename the 2nd sheet, if necessary, to the same name as the 1st sheet that you had

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late with the answer to this question, I had the same problem and to solve this I've done following:

1. Created a fake first line holding my formula in both formula sheet and the sheet where I extract the data
2. Made this first line hidden in both sheets
3. Now when the user deletes the data with my script, the formula gets pulled out of the hidden line again, which can't be broken because it's linked to a line which wont be deleted. (Note that it's smartest to protect these line so people can't accidently delete it)
4. If you don't work with vba, you can manually do the same: unhide, unprotect and drag the formula down again

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have done this in the past. I use it when i delete a sheet during the execution of code. The general process is as follows with the particular procedure below. Please note you need to define the public variable at the top of a module

```
Option Explicit
Public arFormulasToKeep as Variant


Sub SomeProcessThatRemovesReference()

  'Procedure that stores formulas in public variable
   Call StoreValidationFormulas(TheRangeToStoreFormulas)

       'Your codes execution here
       'Sheet deletes that breaks reference
       '
       '
       ' 
  'Return formulas back to range
   Call ReturnFormulasBackToRange(TheRangeToStoreFormulas)


End Sub 'SomeProcessThatRemovesAsReference()


'----------------------------------------------------------------------------



Sub StoreValidationFormulas(rngToStoreFormulas As Range)
'Call this before you delete the sheet or break the reference

'Public variable that will store formulas in memory until you need to insert   again 
 arFormulasToKeep = ReturnFormulasFromRange(rngToStoreFormulas)

End Sub


Public Function ReturnFormulasFromRange(rRange As Range) As Variant
'This will go and store formulas only into array that is the exact dimension/order as the range you have passed, you could alter this funciton to return everything

Dim arFXs
Dim i, j As Long

ReDim arFXs(1 To rRange.Rows.Count, 1 To rRange.Columns.Count)

    For i = 1 To rRange.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rRange.Columns.Count

            If rRange.Cells(i, j).HasFormula = True Then
                arFXs(i, j) = rRange.Cells(i, j).FormulaR1C1
            Else
                arFXs(i, j) = ""
            End If

        Next j
    Next i
'Pass back to function
 ReturnFormulasFromRange = arFXs

End Function

Sub ReturnFormulasBackToRange(rngToReturnFormulas as range)
'''Now return stored formulas back to range
Dim i, j As Long

For i = 1 To rngToReturnFormulas.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rngToReturnFormulas.Columns.Count
        If arFormulasToKeep (i, j) <> "" Then
            rngToReturnFormulas.Cells(i, j).FormulaR1C1 = arFormulasToKeep(i, j)
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```