# How can I concatenate to reference a cell from a deleted sheet without breaking the formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Let me try to explain myself, I'm working in a Excel file, where I created some formulas that reference another sheet, but when this sheet was deleted, all my formulas used to break, so I found on the internet this [method](https://superuser.com/questions/348994/excel-how-to-delete-sheets-without-breaking-formula-references#1191627), problem solved, the issue that I'm having now is that I only want to reference the sheet, not a range of cells in a sheet, let me explain it:

What I did and following the answer I told you above, I wrote in a cell `Sheet!A$1:E$100` as pure text, and reference to it in my formula like this `=indirect($a$1)`, what I want now is to have a dinamic cell, but referencing the same Sheet.

So what I tried was, writing pure text in my cell `a1`: `Sheet!` and in my formula:
`=indirect($a$1)a2`, of course it didn't work.

So I tried to concatenate both

```
=concatenate(indirect($a$1),a2)
```

and it didn't work either, I want to have that cell dynamic, so I can drop my mouse down and the formulas look like this:

```
=indirect($a$1)a2
=indirect($a$1)a3
=indirect($a$1)a4
```

How can I concatenate it? What is the correct way to do it and the formula? Is it only an error on mine? If you need any clarificaction please let me know.

Edit:
Is there another way to make my formula dynamic? Not neccesary using `concatenate()`

Comment: I think the problem with your concatenate formula is that excel thinks `a2` is a cell reference. Add double quotes should look like this `=concatenate(indirect($a$1),"a2")`. I don't think this is going to play nice and increment when you drag down.

Comment: @gns100 is there another way to do it? to make the formula dynamic? (Not neccesary using ```concatenate()``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is not easy to understand, but this might be the answer:

Have the Sheet reference (e.g. the text `Sheet` and nothing more) in A1,
then use `=A1 & "!" & CELL("address";A4)` to **show** the complete 'external sheet'-cell reference (full address).

This can then be used as in `=INDIRECT(A1 & "!" & CELL("address";A4))` to get the value from A4 in that external Sheet.

**NOTE:** Excel uses `!` (exlamation) between the Sheet name and Cell address, LibreOffice uses `.` (period).

With `Sheet1` in A1 and A4 referenced as above, any value in A4 will show up with a copy in the cell with the `=INDIRECT(...)` formula above. If you clear the content of cell A4, it will be taken (read) as `0` via the reference.

--- csv file, for LibreOffice ---

```
Sheet1

"=INDIRECT(A1 & ""."" & CELL(""address"",A4))"
```

Replace `.` with `!` to have it work for Excel

Comment: It worked, thank you!